# The third absolute central moment of the lognormal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there an analytic expression for $E|X-EX|^{3}$ of a lognormal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick session with the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica*:

[image]

where `Erf` denotes the: [Error function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Erf.html)

I have given the computer-generated solution a quick check using Monte Carlo methods, and it seems fine. Note ... with anything other than small values for $\mu$ and $\sigma$, such expressions can be decidedly 'explosive'.

Comment: Wow...that is great. I think I'll look into getting Mathmatica 9 and the mathStatica add on :)

Comment: kaching!${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you check wikipedia you will find the skewness formula. skeness is equal to $E[(X-\mu)^3/\sigma^3]$ so you should be able to get what you want.

Comment: Umm - he is seeking the the third _absolute_ central moment ... not the third central moment.

Comment: Right ! Sorry I had missed that... my fault